# SUMIF of multiple columns with INDIRECT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Excel sheet which is used as database, let's call that `MyDB` in the following Example. The first column `A` consists of some strings.

```
A                | B            | C 
-----------------|--------------|------------------------------------------
Turnover 2014    | 1            | 2
Something        | 2            | 0
Something        |              | 
Turnover 2014    | 3            | 1
Something        |              | 
Something        | 0            | 2
```

What I want to do is look for the string `Turnover 2014` and sum all values in that row from B:C (C is just an example in my case it will be variable and can be F or M).

**What I have:**

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'MyDB'!A"&Helper!D2&":"&"A"&Helper!D8),"=Turnover 2014",INDIRECT("'MyDB'!$B"&Helper!D2&":"&"B"&Helper!D8))
```

The `Helper!D2` and `Helper!D8` contain the variable range, which is one of the reasons I have to use `INDIRECT`. For this example lets assume `D2 = 1` and `D8 = 6` (the full table)

Simple version:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'MyDB'!A1:A6"),"=Turnover 2014",INDIRECT("'MyDB'!B1:B6"))
```

This sums all values in `B` where `A = Turnover 2014`, so no problem here. Now I will show you my attempts to do the same with multi-columns:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'MyDB'!A1:A6"),"=Turnover 2014",INDIRECT("'MyDB'!B1:C6"))

=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("'MyDB'!A1:A6") = "Turnover 2014")*(INDIRECT("'MyDB'!B1:C6")))
```

Both didn't work in my case (IMPORTANT I'm not talking about the simplified version I'm talking about the original version with all the variables).

In all cases I only get the sum of `4` where I need `7`

Comment: I get `7` with the `SUMPRODUCT` version, [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nrRk3.png).

Comment: your formulas works fine for me (both, simplified and with `"'MyDB'!A"&Helper!D2&":"&"A"&Helper!D8`). Check whether your col A contains `Turnover 2014` without trailing/leading spaces. And also try 1) `=SUMPRODUCT((TRIM(INDIRECT("'MyDB'!A"&Helper!D2&":"&"A"&Helper!D8)) = "Turnover 2014")*(INDIRECT("'MyDB'!B"&Helper!D2&":"&"C"&Helper!D8)))`. 2) also you can do it withoud INDIRECT: `=SUMPRODUCT((TRIM(INDEX(MyDB!$A:$A,Helper!D2):INDEX(MyDB!$A:$A,Helper!D8)) = "Turnover 2014")*(INDEX(MyDB!$B:$B,Helper!D2):INDEX(MyDB!$C:$C,Helper!D8)))` - which is much better because it's not volatile formula

Comment: @simoco thank you, I guess I missed some edge condition which I'll have to figure out. Or I fixed something during my translation of the formula which I don't see on my excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your column A contains `Turnover 2014` without leading/trailing spaces.

And try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
 (TRIM(INDIRECT("'MyDB'!A"&Helper!D2&":"&"A"&Helper!D8)) = "Turnover 2014")*
 (INDIRECT("'MyDB'!B"&Helper!D2&":"&"C"&Helper!D8))
)
```

also I suggest you to take a look at alternative formula without `INDIRECT` which is much better because it's *not volatile* formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
 (TRIM(INDEX(MyDB!$A:$A,Helper!D2):INDEX(MyDB!$A:$A,Helper!D8))="Turnover 2014")*
 (INDEX(MyDB!$B:$B,Helper!D2):INDEX(MyDB!$C:$C,Helper!D8))
)
```